# Unable tag branch name as tag name with docker image in Jenkins pipeline file

Tags: image, docker, continuous-integration, jenkins-pipeline

In my scenario I am trying to add tag name as a branch name and date with version number using groovy script. If we print the branch name date we can see them in console. But if we are trying to add both as tag names we are getting error. Please find the below script for reference.

```
    pipeline {
  environment {
    dockerImage = ''
    imageName = 'gcr.io/projectName/web-ui'
    tag = VersionNumber(versionNumberString: '${BUILD_DATE_FORMATTED,"yyyyMMdd"}-${BUILDS_TODAY}');
    local = ''
  }
  

  stages {
    stage('Dockerize'){
        steps {
            script {
                local = "${env.GIT_BRANCH}".replace("feature/", "").replace("/", "-")
                echo "${local}"
                dockerTag = "${local}-${tag}"
                echo "${dockerTag}"
                sh 'docker build -t ${imageName}:${dockerTag} .'
                sh 'docker push ${imageName}:${dockerTag}'
  
            }
        }
    }
   

  }
}
```

Below is the error message I am getting.

```
    docker build -t gcr.io/projectname/web-ui: .
invalid argument "gcr.io/projectname/web-ui:" for "-t, --tag" flag: invalid reference format

Console messages for echo statement is :
test
[Pipeline] echo
test-20210416-11
```

Comment: As can be seen in the output, your `dockerTag` variable resolves to an empty string.

Answer (score 0):

When I run this command I get the following:

```
$ docker build -t grc.io/projectName/web-ui:test-20210416-11 .
invalid argument "grc.io/projectName/web-ui:test-20210416-11" for "-t, --tag"
    flag: invalid reference format: repository name must be lowercase
See 'docker build --help'.
```

I don't know if `projectName` is your actual repository name or if this is just obfuscated, but you should review the [naming restrictions on docker repositories](https://docs.docker.com/docker-hub/repos/#creating-repositories).  Namely:

> The repository name needs to be unique in that namespace, can be two to 255 characters, and can only contain lowercase letters, numbers, hyphens (-), and underscores (_).

Comment: No kthompso, Just for reference I added that name. I am keeping all small letters only for project name. Here while i am tying to concatenate branch name then only I am getting error. If It is only date and version we can create the image.